# Are the spaces $[3,7)$ and $(-\infty,2]$ homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

Let $[3,7)$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}$. Is it homeomorphic to $(-\infty,2]$?

It seems like they are not, but perhaps I am just not coming up with the right map.

Comment: Why does it seem that they are not? (In fact they are.)

Comment: I guess because I am having trouble coming up with a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you can show that $(0,1]$ and $[1, \infty)$ are homeomorphic. Then use shifts and dilations to get to your situation.

Comment: I'll be back in several minutes if you need more instructions.

Comment: To show $(0,1]$ and $[1,\infty)$ are homeomorphic, we can use the map $f(x)=1/x$. This maps $(0,1]$ into $[1,\infty)$. It is continuous (from calculus) and its inverse is $f^{-1}(x)=1/x$.

Comment: Yes, that's right. Now, note that $(0,1]$ is homeomorphic to $[-1,0)$, just consider $x \mapsto -x$; and $[-1,0)$ is homeomorphic to $[-4,0)$ just consider $x\mapsto 4x$, and $[-4,0)$ is homeomorphic to $[3,7)$ just consider $x\mapsto x + 7$. So we showed $[3,7)$ is homeomorphic to $[1,\infty)$. Now  do something similar to show that $[1, \infty)$ is homeomorphic to $(-\infty,2]$ and you are done.

Comment: And since the function has an inverse, it is a bijection, and familiar calculus results give us that both $f$ and f^{-1}$ are continuous, hence they are homeomorphic?

Comment: Yes, at each step you can show the function is a continuous bijection and its inverse is also continuous. What you mainly need in addition is that the composition of homeomorphism is a homeomorphism. But likely you know this or you get it from composition of bijections is a bijection and compositions of continuous is continuos.

Comment: I'm confused why we need this. Isn't it enough to show that $f$ is continuous, $f^{-1}$ is continuous, and $f$ has a two sided inverse?

Comment: What do you mean by $f$?

Comment: the continuous function from $x$ to $1/x$

Comment: You need to compose this function $f$ with the other functions that I mentioned. For each one it is easy to show that it is a homeomorphism. Then to finish you need that the composition of homeomorphism is a homeomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=2-\tan\left(\dfrac{\pi}{8}(x-3)\right)$, $x\in[3,7)$.

Comment: How did you come up with this?

Comment: If we draw the picture $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, $f(x)=\tan x$, then the rest are just dilation and flipping over $x$-axis something like that.

Comment: The fact that it is one-to-one and onto and bicontinuous need some calculus and trigonometry facts, which I have assumed here.

Comment: I see. The fact that $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous (and so f is homeomorphic) follows from calculus.

Answer (score 0):

How about you map $ x $ into $ 1/(x-7)  + 9/4 $?

Comment: I suppose I should not do homework for others. If that is why I got downvoted, I get the point.